# Hiding DIV if mouse not over, after delay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

```
tooltip = "#tooltip";
```

When adding marker to map I add a listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function () {
                        hideWindow(tooltip);
                    });
```

Which goes to this:

```
function hideWindow(div) {
                var t = setTimeout("jQuery(div).hide()", 1000);
        }
```

Firebug states 'div' is not defined.
Why?

Comment: use `''` `jQuery('div')`

Comment: I don't think closing all DIVs will help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use strings inside the `setTimeout` but a closure.

eg:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  jQuery(div).hide()
}, 1000)
```

Comment: You shouldn't read w3schools anymore for javascript, check https://developer.mozilla.org/en/javascript instead

Answer (score 1):

It's not defined because you're using the string version of `setTimeout` so your variable `div` isn't in scope.  This shouldn't be used if at all possible.

Try this instead:

```
function hideWindow(div) {
    var t = setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery(div).hide();
    }, 1000);
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to use jQuery animations you can put the delay directly in your event handler using `.delay()`:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function () {
    jQuery(tooltip).delay(1000).hide('fast');
});
```

Comment: Using strings is not deprecated, it is not recommended for the same reasons as using eval()

Comment: no, but I'd fire any programmer working for me that used it ;-)

Comment: Poor guys, may be a "you pay me a drink for that, and every time you'll use it again" should be just fine.